# Two timer applets in notification area

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, portable-ubuntu-remix

after installig Ubuntu 10.04 Remix I can see two timer applets in the notification area. When I click on the first one, I can see the current date and the menues "Open Calendar", "Set Time and Date". When I click on the second one (it's a Date with Time field), I can see a small calendar of the current month and a small world map with my defined locations.

I just want to have only one timer to safe some space in the notification area. How to disable one of the two applets?

To click "Remove from Panel" isn't possible in the Remix edition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was really simple:

**sudo apt-get remove indicator-datetime**

I can't remember that I've installed the indicator-datetime applet myself, but it was the solution for my problem.